# Import .ics File and show in Calendar or UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, calendar

I retrieve an .ics file from a certain url. I'd like to present the information of this file in a calendar and/or list view in my own app. I had a look at iCal4Objc("https://github.com/cybergarage/iCal4ObjC") and parsed the information like this:

```
   -(NSMutableArray *)getPlanFromURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSMutableArray *planEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString *storePath = [self loadICSAndReturnPathFromURL:url];

    CGICalendar *parserCalendar = [[CGICalendar alloc]initWithPath:storePath];
    for(CGICalendarObject *planObject in [parserCalendar objects]) {
        for(CGICalendarComponent *component in [planObject components]) {
            for (CGICalendarProperty *icalProp in [component properties]) {
                NSString *icalPropName = [icalProp name];
                NSLog(@"%@",icalPropName);
                if([icalPropName isEqualToString:SUMMARY]) {
                    [self.summaryArray addObject:[icalProp value]];
                }

                else if([icalPropName isEqualToString:LOCATION]) {
                    [self.locationArray addObject:[icalProp value]];
                }

                else if([icalPropName isEqualToString:CATEGORIES]) {
                    [self.categoryArray addObject:[icalProp value]];

                }

                else if([icalPropName isEqualToString:DTSTART]) {
                    [self.startArray addObject:[icalProp dateValue]];

                }

                else if([icalPropName isEqualToString:DTEND]) {
                    [self.endArray addObject:[icalProp dateValue]];

                }
            }
        }

    }

    for(int i = 0;i<[self.summaryArray count];i++) {
        DECalEntry *entry = [[DECalEntry alloc]init];
        entry.summary = [self.summaryArray objectAtIndex:i];
        entry.roomInformation = [self.locationArray objectAtIndex:i];
        entry.category = [self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:i];
        entry.startDate = [self.startArray objectAtIndex:i];
        entry.endDate = [self.endArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([entry.category isEqualToString:@"Prüfung"]) {
            entry.isExam = true;
        }
        else entry.isExam = false;

        [planEntries addObject:entry];

    }

    return planEntries;

}

-(NSString *)loadICSAndReturnPathFromURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                          returningResponse:&response
                                                      error:&error];

    if (error == nil)
    {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *storePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"planData.ics"];

        [data writeToFile:storePath atomically:YES];
        return storePath;

    }
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);

    return nil;
}
```

Since this is not very clean and it would be a pain to also implement UITableView and a calendar view to illustrate the parsed data i asked me whether there exists a framework that one of you knows which already can handle .ics files and shows them accordingly.

If you have an idea how to solve this issue less complicated and/or with less effort i would be really grateful.

Also have a look at my comment. At the moment the rrule property is not considered at all. But this is very important since it shows me if a event is repeated, until it is repeated and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind i got it working myself by parsing the rrule property like i did it with the other properties and constructed a method which creates the right amount of objects i need by following the information that this property contains. Well i just think this was the only way because apparently the is no framework for importing and parsing .ics files. When i finish my project i might give it a shot for people who might face this one day.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no framework or control provided by Apple that displays .ics files, but once you construct an EKEvent, there is:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventEditViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009571

Specifically, you want to take a look at EventKitUI.framework.

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look at it and update this question when i get first results.

Comment: Ok i had a look at this, but to me it looks like it doesn't really help me because i still would have to parse the information and then construct the EKEvent. The main problem i am facing is that .ics files have a property called RRULE which defines that appointments should be repeated every x day until some date. It is really hard to parse all the information and then ALSO consider this rrule. Thats why i hoped there was some framework where i can easily parse/and or illustrate information from an .ics file

Comment: OK... your question was about whether there was a UI component that would both parse and display a calendar event... I responded with no, there isn't, but there is a calendar display/addition control.  Anyway, glad you figured out your problem.